# resolving Weblogic dependencies works fine at compile time but fails at runtime

Tags: java, oracle, maven, weblogic

I've set up a simple Weblogic client as a Maven project which resolves weblogic's dependencies from

> maven.oracle.com

It compiles fine with `mvn install`, but when actually running it with

```
java -verbose -cp target/simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.test.App
```

it dies with :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/xml/crypto/wss/provider/CredentialProvider
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 6 more

If `weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider` was not in fact found then it would also fail at compile time, but it doesn't.

What could be wrong with it? is it a configuration error?
thanks

@duffymo was correct.After installing the shade plugin and inspecting the generated package, I see that the dependency is missing.

Here is my pom.xml file's dependencies which draws from maven.oracle.com

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope> </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlsafclient</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version> </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlclient</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version> </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wljmsclient</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version> </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Check your assumptions: believe the JVM.  It's not available at runtime if you didn't create a fat JAR with Maven that has all the dependencies inside.  Open the JAR, look at the manifest and contents, and see if it's there for yourself.  If you can't find it, neither can the JVM.

Comment: Use the Maven shade plugin: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: yes you are right.I packaged it with the shade plugin and then inspected the resulting jar file.The given package is missing.But how does it compile? please check my pom.xml file after I edit my main post

Comment: How does it compile?  Maven is making it available when you execute that lifecycle step.  Compiling and running are clearly separate.  Your mistake is thinking that successful compilation guarantees success at runtime.  Stop telling yourself that.  You have to get that JAR into the package so the JVM can find it.